# How do I close a Meetup Group and cancel payments

Tags: meetup

Meetup.com clearly is making this a difficult thing to figure out how to do, even contacting them is a difficult thing to do..

I'd like to close a meetup group that I organize, and discontinue payments.  How is this done?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to go to your meetup URL and add "/closing/" at the end of it.

For example, `meetup.com/group-name/closing/`

Done! :)

Comment: Brilliant.  Absolutely ridiculous that this is the only way to do this, but brilliant.

Comment: Yup! And just to add: This also automatically cancels the organizer subscription (if this has been the only group you were an organizer of).

Comment: Thank you! meetup.com online help was of no use

Answer (score 5):

Meetup now make [this process](http://help.meetup.com/customer/portal/articles/465011) much simpler to go through yourself, without having to email them to do it for you.

They still recommend contacting your members and trying to find another member to step up as organizer. If you still want to close it entirely:

> Head on over to your Meetup Group’s homepage and choose the Step down
>   as Organizer option from the My profile drop down menu.
>
> From there choose a reason for why you’re stepping down as Organizer,
>   then click ‘continue’. On the confirmation page, scroll down and
>   choose ‘Or close down this Meetup completely and don’t allow anyone to
>   step up as Organizer’.
>
> If you need to manage your Organizer Dues plan or end your
>   subscription, go to your [Account](http://www.meetup.com/account/subscription/) page.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is no direct way to do this, which is odd. Anyway,

> If you'd like to *completely* close the Meetup Group, so that no other
>   member can step up to fill the Organizer position, there are some best
>   practices we ask Organizers to consider following first:
>
> Within your 'Group Settings', on the 'Your members' page, set the
>   Meetup Group so that it's no longer accepting new members in the 'How
>   members join your group' section. In 'Basics', change the name to
>   something like 'Closing Down XYZ Meetup Group!'  Send a message to
>   your membership letting them know what's happening.
>
> If you feel comfortable that you're ready to go, please send a message
>   to the Meetup Community Team, and we'll take care of finishing the
>   process from here.
>
> NOTE: If you've *already* contacted the Community Team about closing
>   the Group completely, you can send your confirmation by replying
>   directly to the email you received. You don't have to go through the
>   contact form and start over again.

[Source](http://www.meetup.com/help/How-do-I-delete-my-Meetup-Group/)

Comment: I've added a new answer to include the current process.

Comment: I clicked cancel subscription link, but nothing happened even after 2 weeks. Support doesn't respond and just marks my requests as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to settngs, subscriptions, ther is a link on the bottom--not easy to spot--that is "Cancel subscription"